# React Apollo Client useQuery Hook gql Uncaught TypeError:(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

So I want to use the Apollo Client react hook "useQuery" to query my graphql backend running Apollo Server.

But the defined query const of will return me an error which is: Uncaught TypeError:(...) is not a function and thus the page is not rendering at all.

My ApolloClient and Provider Setup is as follows:

*index.js*:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { ApolloLink, from } from 'apollo-link';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL });
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        );
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
    httpLink,
    uploadLink
  ]),
  cache,
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
});

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the App Component will trigger the query:

*components/game/GamePage.js*:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import GameForm from './gameform';
import GameRules from './gamerules';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

class GamePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    this.GET_ALL_PLAYERS = gql`
      query allPlayers {
        allPlayers {
          id
          name
          nickname
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  state = { selectedGame: 'X01' };

  componentDidMount() {
    // const players = this.props;
    // players.loadPlayers().catch(err => {
    //   alert('Loading players failed. ' + err);
    // });

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(this.GET_ALL_PLAYERS);

    if (loading) console.log('Loading...');
    if (error) console.log(`Error! ${error.message}`);
    console.log(data);
  }

  handleSubmit = gameObject => {
    console.log(gameObject);
    // this.props.createGame(gameObject);
  };

  handleGameChange = game => {
    this.setState({
      selectedGame: game
    });
  };

  render() {
    const styles = {
      margin: '20px'
    };

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h2 style={styles}>Game Setup</h2>
            {/* <GameForm
              players={this.props.players}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              onGameChange={this.handleGameChange}
            /> */}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h2 style={styles}>Game Rules</h2>
            <GameRules game={this.state.selectedGame} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// GamePage.propTypes = {
//   players: PropTypes.array,
//   games: PropTypes.array,
//   createGame: PropTypes.func.isRequired
// };

export default GamePage;
```

And when loading the App it will get me the error mentioned above. I followed like every tutorial I could find within 2 hours googeling and youtubing. But I cannot resolve it myself. Backend is working just fine besides. Tested it with ApolloServer's Webserver testing tool.

The part in question is this:

```js
this.GET_ALL_PLAYERS = gql`
  query playersList {
    allPlayers {
      id
      name
      nickname
    }
  }
`;
```

Here are Images of the error I am getting:
[image: All errors at once]
[image: Error 1 extended]
[image: Error 2 extended]
[image: Error 3 extended]

So any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

---

Edit: new error after changing {gql} import to gql

[image: New error 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your full error, including the trace, but I suspect you're not importing `from` correctly. The `apollo-link` module does export a class named `ApolloLink` but this class does not have a static method with the name `from`. Instead, you're looking for another named export from the same module:

```
import { from } from 'apollo-link'
```

Also please note that the `react-apollo-hooks` module is now deprecated because the hooks API is now part of `react-apollo`. You should upgrade `react-apollo` and utilize only the single ApolloProvider for both hooks and any legacy components.

EDIT:

Looking at your error, the issue is inside the `GamePage` constructor (notice the first line is `at new GamePage`). Again, there's an import issue here because `graphql-tag` doesn't have a named import named `gql`. That module only has a default export as shown in the docs:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
```

Comment: I edited the original post to represent the current state. I followed your instructions and added link as a named import. Also I substituted with @apollo/react-hooks. I moved the code in question into my class constructor of my GamePage. That is acutally the place I will need it later on to fill in data. I also added Pictures to all errors I am getting in the Browser. The error is still the same. Any help still aprreciated. Let me know if more information is needed to narrow down the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PatrickHener please see my edit. You may find it helpful to utilize an IDE like VS Code that has autocompletion for imports, methods, etc. That way if you start typing a named import or method name and don't see it pop up, you'll know something's wrong before you even run your code.

Comment: I do in fact use VS Code. But I will look into what you said this evening. If it happens to be so easy to fix it then I'll be more than grateful. Thanks

Comment: Well at least the error is now a different one. @Daniel Rearden. My Browser is now telling me that: react-dom.development.js:16178 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. See also the updated Picture in my edit above

Comment: Does this mean instead of using class extends and constructor with props I need to transfer it to a function and use "useState"? Would be easily doable I guess?

Comment: Gonna do that then. Your help is much appritiated. Thanks buddy.